# bat: pass in folder with spaces

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I am writing a bat that outputs to a filepath but am getting stuck on writing to a folder when it contains spaces. I understand this is usually handled by quoting but I must be misunderstanding how to do it right. An example:

I have a folder called "oof oof" and a script.bat containing:

```
echo "%1" > "%2.txt"
```

Run: script.bat "foo foo" "oof oof/oof.txt"

Expected: In folder "oof oof", oof.txt contains: foo foo

Actual: In working directory, oof contains: ""foo foo""

How can I get it to write to the folder?

Comment: And what about `echo "%~1" > "%~2.txt"`

Comment: @Hackoo That did it thanks, always good to learn a new operator

Comment: Your example includes a trailing space character. In order not to have one, you should use either `(Echo %~1) > "%~2"`, `(Echo %~1) 1> "%~2"`, `> "%~2" Echo %~1`, `1> "%~2" Echo %~1`, `> "%~2" (Echo %~1)`, or `1> "%~2" (Echo %~1)`. To see the available expansion 'operators', take a look at the output from entering `call /?` within a Command Prompt window.

Comment: substitution of variable references like `%~2` can also be found in `for /?`

Comment: To not add a CRLF character, you can use `<nul set /p "=%~1"> "%~2"` as it doesn't create a new line.